# Logo design with TiKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, logos

I'm working on a logo meant to evoke the old "Union Made" labels of the late nineteenth and early twentieth century (like [this](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/7f/b7/8c/7fb78cdc95b0cd6bc45ad7f65aa8e224--union-logo-vintage-graphic-design.jpg) or [this](https://lvwrk.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/broomandwhisk1.jpg)).

## What I've got so far

[image: union logo]

## How I got here

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text} % Allows us to wrap text around a circle

\setmainfont{Futura} % Historically appropriate

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        % Draw double circle with text in the gap

        \draw [double distance=10mm,
               very thick,
               rotate=200,
               postaction={
                    decorate,
                    decoration={
                          raise=-1.4ex,
                          text along path, 
                          reverse path,
                          text align={left},
                          text={|\Huge|Newton Teachers Association 2017}
                    }
               }
            ] (0,0) circle (3cm);

        % Include "union made"

        \node[label=above:{\Huge UNION}] at (0,0.75) {};
        \node[label=below:{\Huge MADE}] at (0,-0.75) {};

        % Include clasped hands image

        \pgftext{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{Handshake2.png}} at (0pt,0pt);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Questions

1. I need to re-orient the year, so that it's centered (and right side up) at the bottom of the logo. (See the linked images above.) How can I do that? I tried adding a second `decoration` element, but that didn't work.
2. The circles are drawn as `very thick`, which AFAIK is the boldest line TiKZ has to offer, but they still look a little light for this purpose. Is there any way to embolden them further?

Comment: `ultra thick`? `line width=10pt`? You can put one decoration in `preaction` and one in `postaction`.

Comment: `ultra thick` is in the manual, you know. As is `line width`, along with `very thick` and so on. OK, you're drawing a white circle to obscure the `preaction`. A different `\path` then.

Comment: @cfr I will be more diligent next time instead of trying to work from memory. Mea culpa, etc.

Comment: No problem. It just seemed odd not to look it up, since you obviously knew that you could change the line width and obviously knew quite a bit about Ti*k*Z.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please try to post examples everyone can compile. Your document requires a proprietary font and a personal image, even though neither is essential to the issue you want help with.

My example, in an attempt to 'look correctly wrong' follows suit. Even so, *you* won't be able to compile it, any more than *I* can compile your code.

You can use `ultra thick` or `line width=90mm` or whatever you desire. For the second decoration, you could use a `preaction`, but the white circle you're using will overwrite it. So, use a second `\path`.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz,gtamacfutura}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text} % Allows us to wrap text around a circle
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{cauldron}};
  \draw [double distance=10mm,
  line width=2pt,
  postaction={
    decorate,
    decoration={
      raise=-1.4ex,
      text along path,
      text align={center},
      text={|\Huge\sffamily|Newton Teachers Association}
    },
  },
  ] (-90:30mm) arc (270:-90:3cm);
  \path [
    decorate,
    decoration={
      raise=-1.4ex,
      text along path,
      text align={center},
      text={|\Huge\sffamily|2017}
    },
  ] (180:30mm) arc (180:360:30mm) ;
  \node[label=above:{\Huge\sffamily UNION}] at (0,0.75) {};
  \node[label=below:{\Huge\sffamily MADE}] at (0,-0.75) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Compile with pdfTeX:

[image: union made logo]

Comment: this code results `! LaTeX Error: File `gtamacfutura.sty' not found.` when using `pdflatex`. And in `pdftex` it shows `undefined control sequence \documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}`

Comment: @alhelal Please read my answer. Of course you can't compile it. Don't I say so? If you want it to look like this, you need a copy of Futura. Otherwise, just change the font.